# Why does the delegate call didSelectRowAtIndexPath when I tap an element that has its own handler?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a situation where elements in a `UITableViewCell` subclass have either tap gesture recognizers or `UIButtons`.

When I tap these, not only do its handlers get called, but so does the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method.

Now, ideally, if the user doesn't tap any of those elements, this should be passed on to the view underneath (i.e. the tableview or table cell) and be processed.

Why aren't these elements swallowing the touches and preventing the TableView delegate method from firing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "hacked" a solution which puts a tapGesture recognizer on the contentView of my UITableViewCell subclasses, whose delegate is my custom UITableViewController subclass.  I use an empty didSelectRowAtIndexPath: implementation.  The delegate method is

```
- (void)didSelectTableCell:(MyTableViewCell*)aCell;
```

And that did the job.  Just need to remember when the cell is created to make sure I set the delegate.

Inelegant, but works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the following function..

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

Here you can check if the touch was initiated from a control of your choice and if that is the case you need to return NO to prevent default action from happening here .. and return YES if the earlier defined handler is to be called

```
-(BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
    if(touch.view == self.playButton ) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: override it on what object?  I want to prevent the UITableViewCell subclass from receiving a touch